# How to generate JAXB classes from just XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to generate classes from xml that doesn't provide a schema. I understand this is near useless, but the fact is we have xml, it's structured, and we should be able to create a model from the xml. In the past I've done it by hand, but the current xml documents I am working with are quite large and my time would probably be better spent building something that does what I need. But, I am guessing it has already been done, and I just can't find it.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are many tools available (a quick google search should fetch you some) that can generate XSD from XML assuming string type for almost everything. You should be able to use that XSD to run JAXB to get classes.

Here's an [online tool](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx) that lets you do that.

And here is a screen cap:
[image]

Comment: @Yauhen, not sure why, but your link didnt work for me but Bala R's did - my xml is very complex though

Comment: I don't understand why you posted this online tool instead of posting Java Code. That's not what I am looking for...

Comment: For some reason that site doesn't seem to be working right now, but Google "xml schema generator" shows there are several. Here is one from Liquid: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-to-xsd-converter

Comment: these all online xml tools don't work with large xmls so they are pretty useless

Answer (score 14):

From your xml file, you can create a XML Schema Definition (XSD) file. Once you have the XSD, you'll be able to generate the code, need it be for java, C#, C++, or all of the above.

If you have Visual Studio, you can use xsd.exe to generate the XSD file.

References:

- www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx
- msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx
- Command Syntax: xsd file.xml [/outputdir:directory]
- so **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\xsd.exe"
  example.xml** yields a example.xsd file in the same directory as the
  xml file.

XSD to Java:
Reference:

- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2006/jw-0626-jaxb.html
- Command Syntax: **xjc your.xsd -p com.example.package -d
  src/generatedOutputDirectory**

XSD to C++:
References:

- stackoverflow.com/questions/445905/xml-schema-to-c-classes
- www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/

XSD to C#: 
Reference:

- quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/xmlserialization/XSDToCls.aspx
- Command Syntax: **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft
  SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\xsd.exe" -c -l:c# -n:SomeNameSpace
  example.xsd**

Comment: Javaworld link is now dead..https://web.archive.org/web/20170724100142/http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071784/enterprise-java/java-xml-mapping-made-easy-with-jaxb-2-0.html

Comment: For Java, if you have downloaded the JDK you will have commands like xjc in a folder like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin - you can then add that to the path to be able to use the command.

Answer (score 1):

If the XML was created by JAXB, it can easily be converted back into objects. There's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing3.html) over at oracle which illustrates one way to do this. Spring framework offers similiar features using JAXB which are very conveniant.