# XML to Java Objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have searched all the questions related to this topic but i didnt find an answer to this. I am trying to convert an xml doc to java object. After searching for options to do the same, I found jaxb as the best option to do the same. I referred many articles and came up with this solution which is not working. Can somebody help me in this.

XML  Dod:

```
<Vectors>
    <Vector>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>abc</Name>
         <Desc>abcdefg</Desc>
         <Type>body</Type>
         <Snippet>
            <![CDATA[<total>1234</total>]]>
         </Snippet>
    </Vector>
    <Vector>
         <Id>2</Id>
         <Name>def</Name>
         <Desc>abcdefghigj</Desc>
         <Type>body</Type>
         <Snippet>
            <![CDATA[<total>12345</total>]]>
         </Snippet>
     </Vector>
</Vectors>
```

I want to create 2 java objects of class Vector. Class Vector looks as given below

```
    package com.abc.TryXmltoJava;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

    public class Vector {
        int Id,
        String Name;
        String Desc;
        String Type;

        @XmlElement
        public String getName() {
             return Name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
             this.Name = name;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public String getDesc() {
            return Desc;
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.Desc = desc;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public String getType() {
            return Type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.Type = type;
        }
}
```

Now i have created Vectors class which keeps track of the two objects and creates a list of Vector objects using list utility..

```
 package com.abc.TryXMLtoObject;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

 @XmlRootElement(name="Vectors")
 public class Vectors {

 @XmlElement(name="Vector")
     Vector vector;


     public Vector getVector() {
        return vector;
     }

     public void setVector(Vector vector1) {
        this.vector = vector1;
     }
}
```

I will try to unmarshall the xml object using these two classes which create a list of java objects. Unmarshalling class is as given below..

```
  package com.abc.TryXMLtoObject;

  import java.io.File;
  import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
  import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
  import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

  public class JAXBExampleUnmarshal {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {

          File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
          JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Vectors.class);

          Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
          Vectors vectors = (Vectors) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
          System.out.println(vectors);

         } catch (JAXBException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }

   }
 }
```

After running this code.. i get the following errors:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Vectors"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.abc.TryXMLtoObject.JAXBExampleUnmarshal.main(JAXBExampleUnmarshal.java:17)
```

Comment: Try adding the namespace

Comment: Could this be a typo? (uri:"", local:"Vkectors"). "Vkectors" doesn't look right.

Comment: yup that was a typo.. but i am still  getting the same error i.e local: "Vectors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following version of your example worked for me:

**Vectors**

As [pointed out by popfalushi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508211/383861), `Vectors` should have a `List` property that holds on to many instances of `Vector`.

```
package com.abc.TryXmltoJava;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Vectors")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Vectors {

    @XmlElement(name="Vector")
    List<Vector> vector;

}
```

**Vector**

If you wish to specify the JAXB annotations on the fields, then you should specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the type level (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).  Also the default mapping is `@XmlElement` so you don't explicitly need to add that annotation (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html).

```
package com.abc.TryXmltoJava;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Vector {
    int Id;
    String Name;
    String Desc;
    String Type;
}
```

**JAXBExampleUnmarshal**

I updated your demo code to write the objects back to XML, to prove that the objects were completely populated during the unmarshal operation.

```
package com.abc.TryXmltoJava;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class JAXBExampleUnmarshal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Vectors.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Vectors vectors = (Vectors) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(vectors);

            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(vectors, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**file.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vectors>
    <Vector>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>abc</Name>
         <Desc>abcdefg</Desc>
         <Type>body</Type>
         <Snippet>
            <![CDATA[<total>1234</total>]]>
         </Snippet>
    </Vector>
    <Vector>
         <Id>2</Id>
         <Name>def</Name>
         <Desc>abcdefghigj</Desc>
         <Type>body</Type>
         <Snippet>
            <![CDATA[<total>12345</total>]]>
         </Snippet>
     </Vector>
</Vectors>
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
com.abc.TryXmltoJava.Vectors@44fe9319
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vectors>
   <Vector>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>abc</Name>
      <Desc>abcdefg</Desc>
      <Type>body</Type>
   </Vector>
   <Vector>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>def</Name>
      <Desc>abcdefghigj</Desc>
      <Type>body</Type>
   </Vector>
</Vectors>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. btw what this means "@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)"

Comment: @Sanket - By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will create metadata for all public fields.  If you want your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation to base the metadata on the fields instead you can specify `@XmlAccesorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.  See: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 3):

At first, you in `Vectors` you must have `List<Vector> vectorList`, not one singular `Vector`.
Also, text from stacktrace `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Vkectors")` tells me, that somewhere in xml you have `Vkectors` element, and thats wrong.
Lastly, I strongly recommend you to put all annotations to get-methods, not to variable for two reasons: there was some name collision, if my memory is right, and secondly, if you'll have proxies from Hibernate or something like that, annotations from fields will disappear, but annotations for get-methods will stay.

Comment: Oh.. Yes.. will check that and let you know, if it works or not

Comment: +1 - To avoid the name collision issue when annotating fields, `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` should be specified on the class:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: if you have annotated field `field1` with `@XmlElement`, and you have method `getField1()`, than you'll get name collision. You can have annotated `field1` with accessor `getProperty1(){return field1;}` though, but that seems to be ugly to me.

Comment: @popfalushi - Did you see my note about `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`?

Comment: My apologies. I saw that name of the field and accessors name differ and thought that it proves my point of view. Now checked it locally, and discovered that you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to restore objects could you first create them in Java and persist using JAXB? Then you'll see the difference between your XML file and the one JAXB produces.

Answer (score 1):

First, your stack trace names `Vekctors` (note the k), so it might be a typo. But then it says "Expected elements are (none)". In your `Vectors` class you only have declared a `Vector` element, so it you can't put two elements inside the `Vectors` element.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to look at this answer that discusses hos to [generate classes from an xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995466/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-just-xml). It also provides a link to a resource to generate an xsd from raw xml.

Your stack trace also refers to "Vkectors" - was their a typo in the source file?

Lastly, you may wish to start with the [jaxb tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/index.html) and work your way up from there.

Good luck!