# how to generate jaxb class from xml without xsd directly?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

## I need to generate jaxb classes from xml file without xsd.

Now I have found one way to generate xsd files firstly, then use **xjc** command to generate jaxb classes :'
[How to generate JAXB classes from just XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995466/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-just-xml) '.

My question is, is there any simple tools to generate jaxb classes from just xml file directly?

Answer (score 0):

Not much. Generating classes directly from XML doesn't produce your desired result. For example element `<name>` in your XML file can occur how many times and which java type are unclear to generating java code. If it can occur multiple times it should be java `Collection<String>` or once `String`.

I suggest you to use graphical XSD creator tools. Most developers bothered writing bulky XSDs(namespaces, prefixes) but when you use graphical tools its easy as writing XMLs.

I have been using Liquid XML Studio but there are many alternatives.

Comment: well , thanks any way. Cause I feel it is boring writing XSDs, so I want to find a easier way.