# how to convert string in the form of xml to xml format in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, mule, esb

I have xml data in the form of string. I would like to know how to convert it using Java.

In MULE ESB I have the string message in logger showing it as:

## [payload:java.lang.String]

I need to store each elements and give a response in XML.
How do I configure it with JAXB or any other process?

```
<EAI_MESSAGE>
<EAI_HEADER>
                <MsgFormat>ISO8583</MsgFormat>
                <MsgVersion>1.0.1.0</MsgVersion>    
</EAI_HEADER>

<EAI_BODY>

    <FundTransferRequest>
                <CustomerId>CT1010</CustomerId>
                <SourceAccNo>12346789012345</SourceAccNo>
                <SourceAccName>SOURAV MUKHERJEE</SourceAccName>
                <SourceAccType>SAVINGS</SourceAccType>
                <SourceIFSC>SBI1010</SourceIFSC>
                <Amount>5000.00</Amount>
    </FundTransferRequest>`enter code here`
</EAI_BODY>
```

Comment: Try using sax parser

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking in the correct direction when you mention JAXB. JDK comes with xjc which allows you to auto-generate classes that are needed to unmarshall and marshall XML files. You can follow the following steps to build a solutions

1. Build XML Schema for input and output XML format. There are number of tools available to achieve this. ([How to generate JAXB classes from just XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995466/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-just-xml))
2. Use the XML schemas to generate JAXB java library. ([Generate your JAXB classes in a second with xjc](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/generate-your-jaxb-classes-in-second/))
3. Now configure you java application to unmarshall (build java objects from XML) using input JAXB library. ([Using JAXB to Generate Java Objects from XML Document](https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-generate-java))
4. Build Java object structure using classes generated using XJC for needed for output XML format using the Java objects created by unmarshalling. This is pure Java programming task
5. Now, generate the output XML needed using marshaller in JAXB library

This seems complex but except for generating output Java data structure from input Java, rest of the process is straight forward. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I'm wondering if there isn't a more up-to-date answer since this was quite a while ago