# Creating java code from XML files with object content

Tags: java, xml

I am searching for a way to parse an XML file in such a way that it generates one .java file for the whole XML with the objects inside the XML being created with the attributes as specified by the XML.

As an example, say you have an XML like:

```
<example>
    <person>
        <name>Tom</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Michael</name>
    </person>
</example>
```

Now what I would like to do is generate java code from this that does this:

```
public void foo() {
    Example example = new Example();

    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.setName("Tom");
    example.getPerson().add(person1);

    Person person2 = new Person();
    person2.setName("Michael");
    example.getPerson().add(person2);
}
```

I am aware of JAXB and that it can unmarshall an XML file to make java objects but from what I know I would end up with an object from which I would need to extract all the relevant information by going through it per reflection which honestly is not something I would like to do.

Is there any code generator available that does what I would need it to do?

EDIT:

I have been pointed to a similar question which addresses the unmarshalling of an XML into an object which is something (as I have stated before) I know of and have used before.

In essence, taken from [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing3.html), I could do this for example:

```
PurchaseOrder po = (PurchaseOrder)u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("po.xml"));
```

Yet this would leave me with an object `PurchaseOrder` which I would then need to make something like an `objectBuilder` myself.

I could also get the class definitions using JAXB but I have the definitions already. I just want to build java code by going through the XML that creates all objects and fills their attributes according to the XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate JAXB classes from just XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995466/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-just-xml)

Comment: Don't really get it. If you already have the Class definitions can't you add JAXB annotations to them and just unmarshal ?

Comment: Sadly no as I don't need the objects, I need the java code to generate the objects with. There's another application that uses exactly that code but does not work with `JAXBContext` and unmarshalling which I have tried before.